# SVC mode program's return address after svc instruction

Tags: arm

I'm confused about the returning process of SVC mode's program after svc instruction. Assuming currently the processor is running on SVC mode, then it's interrupted by software interrupt by svc instruction, hardware would help save CPSR into SPSR_svc, and load svc handler into PC, load the program address where it's interrupted into LR_svc. To return to SVC mode normal program where it's interrupted, we need to load LR_svc into PC, and load SPSR_svc into CPSR.

My question is that, in svc handler, LR_svc is changed, it's context is the program address where it's interrupted, so after the program returns to the normal SVC mode program, the program's LR is changed, how can the program return to the function where it's called???

Comment: which arm core?

Answer (score 0):

> so after the program returns to the normal SVC mode program, the program's LR is changed

Wrong assumtion. The LR is banked for SVC mode, so you changing it in SVC handler does *not* change the register value for user mode.

Comment: yes, LR is a banked register, however it's value is the address where it should return to rather than the copy of the original mode's LR. My assumption is that the program is running at SVC mode, and is interrupted by svc instruction.

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming currently the processor is running on SVC
> mode, then it's interrupted by software interrupt by svc instruction,
> ...
> how can the program return to the function where it's called???

There are 2 ways to make sure that the program returns to the function that called into supervisor mode.
One way is to very carefully write the SVC handler and all the functions it calls (supervisor-mode code that runs in SVC mode), making sure that code has *no* SVC instructions in it.

Another way, as suggested by the ["ARM Developer Suite Developer Guide: Using SWIs in Supervisor mode"](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0056/d/handling-processor-exceptions/swi-handlers/using-swis-in-supervisor-mode):

> If the processor is already in Supervisor mode, lr_SVC and spsr_SVC
> are corrupted.
>
> If you call a SWI while in Supervisor mode you must store lr_SVC and
> spsr_SVC to ensure that the original values of the link register and
> the SPSR are not lost.

SVC handlers that take this approach typically start by pushing those values to the supervisor stack.
After those are saved away, *then* it is safe to use the SVC instruction.
Then later, when the SVC handler is ready to return,
it uses those values on the stack (not the values currently in the lr_SVC and spsr_SVC registers) to return to the correct place.
That way the SVC handler works and then returns correctly either way -- whether it was called using SVC from user-mode code, or whether it was called using SVC from SVC-mode code.

This is similar to the way typical a typical user-mode ARM Thumb or ARM32 subroutine -- let's call it S() --  deals with the return address in LR that it needs to return correctly -- even though LR is overwritten every time S() calls any other user-mode subroutine.
Following the [ARM Thumb or the ARM32 calling conventions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Embedded_Systems/ARM_Microprocessors),
S() begins with instructions that push a copy of the link register to the stack.
When S() is finished, it *doesn't* return to the address currently in the link register (an address that was overwritten and lost when it called some other subroutine).
Instead, S() pulls the return address it earlier saved to the stack, so then M() can correctly return to the correct location in the subroutine that called it.

p.s.:
For future readers looking for information on SVC:

- [The SVC instruction was once called the SWI instruction.](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0473/m/arm-and-thumb-instructions/svc)
- [FreeRTOS port.c includes the SVC handler](https://github.com/FreeRTOS/FreeRTOS-Kernel/blob/main/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4_MPU/port.c)
- ["ARM Cortex-M RTOS Context Switching"](https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/cortex-m-rtos-context-switching)
- ["The M3/M4/M7 ports of FreeRTOS [use] ... The SVC (SuperVisor Call) instruction ... the SVC instruction ... is not used for M0."](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2016/08/28/arm-cortex-m-interrupts-and-freertos-part-3/)
- ["Service Time – ARM Cortex-M SVC Exception"](https://www.iotality.com/armcm-svc/)
- ["CMSIS-RTOS: SVC Functions"](https://arm-software.github.io/CMSIS_5/RTOS2/html/theory_of_operation.html)
- ["The... RTOS ... and ... the bootloader, each component has its own SVC handler"](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/40142/freertos-svc-handler-and-buttonless-dfu)